# Pascal program doesnt show the full output

Tags: menu, scroll, console, output, pascal

My school assignment was to create a menu-like program with pascal that shows the code of other programs. It reads the text from a file line by line and prints it to the console. It works just fine to the point when it doesnt show the full output. This is the output that it shows:
http://postimg.org/image/3r4ua8poz/

When it runs it shows everything line by line, but at the end you can only see the part of the code that fits in the console window and you cant scroll up. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? It will be much appresiated.
Here is the actuall code:

```
    program pascalMenu  //ime na programata
{$mode objfpc};//OOP pascal ili neshto takova(zaduljitelno e)
uses sysutils,
 crt, graph;
Var choice : array[1..5] of string;//masiv, v sluchaq sadurja chas ot imenata na failovete
programFile : Text;//shte sudurja imeto na faila
userFile,line,number,filename : string;
i,j,value : integer;
c : char;
begin
        writeln('This program will open all of our previous tasks.');

        //pulnene na masiva
        for i := 1 to 5 do
        begin
                str(i,number);
                choice[i] := 'program' + number;
        end;
        j:=1;

        repeat
        writeln( 'Use the arrow keys to navigate, ENTER to open and ESC to close.');


        //pokazvane na elementite v masiva sled vsqka vrutka na cikula
        for i:= 1 to 5 do
           begin
              if i = j then
              begin
                //tva e za cveta
                 textcolor(red);
                 writeln(choice[i]);
                 textcolor(white);
                 continue;
              end;
              writeln(choice[i]);

           end;

        //beggining the menu loop

        c := readkey;//chetene na kopche rofl
        clrscr;// - chisti konzolata(optional)
        if ord(c) = 0 then
        c := readkey;
        value := ord(c);
        //options
        case value of
        72 :
                begin
                j:= j - 1;
                if j < 1 then j :=5;
                end;
        80:
                begin
                j:= j + 1;
                if j > 5 then j:= 1;
                end;
        13:
                begin
                str(j,number);
                filename := 'program' + number + '.txt';
                assignfile(programFile,filename);//prilaga imeto na faila na promenlivata
                //tva nz za kakvo e, obache sled 5-q opit reshi, che bez nego nemoje
                try
                reset(programFile);//otvarq faila za chetene

                repeat

                        readln(programFile, line);//chete 1 red ot faila v line
                        writeln(line);
                until (Eof(programFile));//eof - end of file
                closefile(programFile);//zaduljitelno!! bez nego ne mogat dase otvarqt 2/poveche faila
                                        //zaradi greshka v read/write dostupa
                except on E:EInOutError do begin
                writeln('The program could not read the file. Check the file''''s''name and directory.');end;
                end;

                writeln('Press any key to return to the main menu.');
                writeln('P.S. - This will erase the text');
                readln;
                clrscr;
                end;
        end;
        until value =27;


end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrolling is prohibited by the use of unit Crt. Unuse it.

Or have a look at the "lister" demo that comes with FPC, which tries a bit of the same (cursor movement for selection and displaying)